# Can I run multiple control but same method in C#

Tags: c#

For Example

```
txtUnitTotalQty.Text = "";   
txtPrice.Text = "";
txtUnitPrice.Text = "";
lblTotalvalue.Text = "";
```

To something like

```
(txtUnitTotalQty, txtPrice, txtUnitPrice, lblTotalvalue).Text = "";
```

Comment: You can also write a method to accept controls as param array and value, set values of all param arrays in that function.

Comment: Please think to accept answer to thank people that spend time to help you : )

Comment: @Fabien OK thank you for remind me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
txtUnitTotalQty.Text = txtPrice.Text = txtUnitPrice.Text = lblTotalvalue.Text = string.Empty;
```

Or you could write a method for it:

```
public void SetText(params TextBox[] controls, string text)
{
    foreach(var ctrl in controls)
    {
        ctrl.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Usage of this would be:

```
SetText(txtUnitTotalQty, txtPrice, txtUnitPrice, lblTotalvalue, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 3):

As .Text is a property of the common base class Control, you can iterate over a list:

```
new List<Control> { txtUnitTotalQty, txtPrice, txtUnitPrice, lblTotalvalue }.ForEach(c => c.Text = "");
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU FOR THE NEW KNOWLEDGE

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way to write the same thing with a smaller function is

```
void ClearAllText(Control con)
{
    foreach (Control c in con.Controls)
    {
      if (c is TextBox)
         ((TextBox)c).Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
foreach (var txt in new[] { txtUnitTotalQty, txtPrice, txtUnitPrice, lblTotalValue} )
{
    txt.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: As the controls are different type, `new []` won't be able to automatically pick a type for the array, so you need to explicitly say `new Control[] { ... }`